# Apple Mail with Gmail, via OAuth

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

I would like to use Apple Mail on Mac OS to access my email account on Gmail.  How do I set this up, without using an app password (i.e., via OAuth)?

Unfortunately, I am unable to create an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) on Google, and my domain does not allow me to enable "[less secure app access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)" for my email address.  So, I cannot use an app password.  Google has announced that "less secure app access" is not available for new users, and will stop being available for anyone on May 30, 2022, so soon everyone will be in the same position I am in -- soon, app passwords will not be allowed for anyone.

Google's help pages say I should use my Google Account to sign in, which I believe means using OAuth.  However I can not see how to configure or enable that in Apple Mail.  When I try to configure Mail using Mail >> Preferences >> Server Settings in the menu, it only provides a place to enter a username and password.  Now what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

In Mail Preferences > Accounts, click the [+] and choose "Google"

[image: Screenshot showing the account type picker, with Google selected]

This will bring up a Google sign-in page:

[image: Screenshot showing Google sign-in page]